# Basic Java: method calculation returns NaN

Tags: java, methods

I'm learning java but having difficulty with creating a method that calculates Body Mass Index. It doesn't accept the instance variables I declared earlier in the program and I'm not sure how to fix this. All help is appreciated!

Code:

```
import java.util.Formatter;
public class HealthRecord
{
     // initialise instance variables

    String first;
    String last;
    double height;
    double weight;

    public HealthRecord(String LastName, String FirstName, double height, double weight)
    {
        first = FirstName;
        last = LastName;
        height = height;
        weight = weight;

    }


    public static void main(String args[]) {

        HealthRecord record = new HealthRecord("Last", "First", 72, 150);
        System.out.println("BMI="+record.getBMI());
    }

      // calculate BMI
    public double getBMI() {
        double bmi = weight / (height * height) * 703.0;
        return bmi;
    }

}
```

Result:
BMI=NaN

Comment: Should be `this.height = height;` and `this.weight = weight;`

Comment: Thanks that works! I'm not sure why though?

Comment: Since you have a field the same name as a constructor parameter, you have to use `this` to indicate the field. Doing `weight = weight` just reassigns the parameter to itself and the field isn't assigned.

Comment: @LukasBarth You weren't initializing `this.width` and `this.height`, so they didn't have a valid value to do math on. You were just reassigning the constructor parameter to itself, which doesn't do anything.

Comment: Just a note: When you create a new 'HealthRecord', I would pass in 'double' types instead of 'integer' types. It is good practice to follow the declaration explicitly and results in code that is easier to read.    ie: HealthRecord record = new HealthRecord("Last", "First", **72.0, 150.0**);

Comment: Put a breakpoint inside that method and debug it. Check the variables values

Answer (score 0):

Update your constructor as below:

```
public HealthRecord(String LastName, String FirstName, double height, double weight)
  {
    first = FirstName;
    last = LastName;
    this.height = height;
    this.weight = weight;

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `HealthRecord` constructor, **you are assigning the values of `height` and `weight` to the method arguments, not to the object/instance variables**.

If you wanted to assign a value to the instance variable, you need to use `this` operator which always refers to the current object (look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html)) and refer the code below:

```
public HealthRecord(String first, String last, 
              double height, double weight) {
        this.first = first;
        this.last = last;
        this.height = height;
        this.weight = weight;
}
```

Also, I have updated argument names to `first` and `last` (method arguments) so that they all consistent as shown above.

I suggest you always use the same variable names for both method arguments and instance variables (make it as a practice) & use `this.` to refer instance variables.